# How to show-hide div element in JavaScript as per select element value?

Tags: javascript, html

Here are options (option 0, option 1 and option 2). If option 1 is selected, the `videoShowHide` should be shown, and hide the `onlineShowHide` and `handoutShowHide`.

HTML:

```js
document.getElementById('type').onchange(function() {
  if (document.getElementById('type').value === 0) {
    document.getElementById('onlineShowHide').classList.add('d-block');
    document.getElementById('handoutShowHide').classList.add('d-none');
    document.getElementById('videoShowHide').classList.add('d-none');
  }
  if (document.getElementById('type').value === 1) {
    document.getElementById('onlineShowHide').classList.add('d-none');
    document.getElementById('handoutShowHide').classList.add('d-block');
    document.getElementById('videoShowHide').classList.add('d-none');
  }
  if (document.getElementById('type').value === 2) {
    document.getElementById('onlineShowHide').classList.add('d-none');
    document.getElementById('handoutShowHide').classList.add('d-none');
    document.getElementById('videoShowHide').classList.add('d-block');
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 mb-3">
  <label for="type" class="form-label">نوع</label>
  <select class="form-select" id="type" name="type">
    <option value="0">Online</option>
    <option value="1">Video</option>
    <option value="2">Handout</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 mb-3" id="onlineShowHide">
  <label for="online" class="form-label">Online</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="online" name="online">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 mb-3 d-none" id="videoShowHide">
  <label for="video" class="form-label">Video</label>
  <input type="file" class="form-control" id="video" name="video">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 mb-3 d-none" id="handoutShowHide">
  <label for="handout" class="form-label">Handout</label>
  <input type="file" class="form-control" id="handout" name="handout">
</div>
```

Comment: As a snippet when ran the error is clearly visible here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To add an event you can do it using `addEventListener` or assign a function to this event like this: `document.getElementById('type').onchange = function() {}`.
2. When you retrieve the value from the `#type` element it will be a string and not a number.
3. You are trying to add `d-block` to the element to show it but you are not removing the already existing `d-none` class so you should rather remove the `d-none` class to show the element.

Example:

```js
let onlineShowHide = document.getElementById('onlineShowHide');
let handoutShowHide = document.getElementById('handoutShowHide');
let videoShowHide = document.getElementById('videoShowHide');

let type = document.getElementById('type');

type.onchange = function () {
      onlineShowHide.classList.add('d-none');
      videoShowHide.classList.add('d-none');
      handoutShowHide.classList.add('d-none');
        
    if(type.value === '0') {
        onlineShowHide.classList.remove('d-none');
    }
    if(type.value === '1') {
        videoShowHide.classList.remove('d-none');
    }
    if(type.value === '2') {
        handoutShowHide.classList.remove('d-none');
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-lg-6 mb-3">
    <label for="type" class="form-label">نوع</label>
    <select class="form-select" id="type" name="type">
        <option value="0">Online</option>
        <option value="1">Video</option>
        <option value="2">Handout</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 mb-3" id="onlineShowHide">
    <label for="online" class="form-label">Online</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="online" name="online">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 mb-3 d-none" id="videoShowHide">
    <label for="video" class="form-label">Video</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="video" name="video">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 mb-3 d-none" id="handoutShowHide">
    <label for="handout" class="form-label">Handout</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="handout" name="handout">
</div>
```